# Printing out / showing detailed steps of proof methods (like simp) in a proof in isabelle

Tags: isabelle, isar

Suppose I have the following code in Isabelle:

```
lemma"[| xs@zs = ys@xs ;[]@xs = []@[] |] => ys=zs" (*never mind the lemma body*)
apply simp
done
```

In the above code, The simp method proves the lemma. I am interested to see and print out the detailed (rewriting /simplification) steps that the simplification method takes to prove this lemma ( and possibly be able to do the same for all the other proof methods). How this is possible?

I am using isabelle 2014 with JEdit  editor.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplifier trace can be enabled by specifying attributes `simp_trace` or `simp_trace_new`:

```
lemma "⟦xs @ zs = ys @ xs; [] @ xs = [] @ [] ⟧ ⟹ ys = zs"
  using [[simp_trace]]
  apply simp
done
```

If the cursor is positioned after the `simp` step, the output pane shows the rewrite trace inline (with the list what rules are added, what are applied and what terms are rewritten).

`simp_trace_new` allows seeing a more compact variant of the trace (what is rewritten) in a separate window (the trace pane is activated by pressing a highlighted part of a message *See **simplifier trace*** in the output pane, the trace itself is shown by pressing a button *Show trace*). Adding an option `mode=full` generates a more detailed output similar to `simp_trace`, but in a more structured way:

```
lemma "⟦xs @ zs = ys @ xs; [] @ xs = [] @ [] ⟧ ⟹ ys = zs"
  using [[simp_trace_new mode=full]]
  apply simp
done
```

You can find more details in [The Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf) that is also included in Isabelle2014 installation.

Answer (score 4):

If you are happy downloading a file or two, the [l4.verified](https://github.com/seL4/l4v/) project includes a tool called [Apply Trace](https://github.com/seL4/l4v/blob/master/lib/Apply_Trace_Cmd.thy) written by Daniel Matichuk. It gives you a new command `apply_trace` that can be used wherever you would ordinarily use `apply`, but will show you the theorems used in the step.

For example, writing:

```
lemma "⟦xs @ zs = ys @ xs; [] @ xs = [] @ [] ⟧ ⟹ ys = zs"
  apply_trace simp
```

produces:

```
used theorems:
  simp_thms(6): (?x = ?x) = True
  append_Nil: [] @ ?ys = ?ys
  append_Nil2: ?xs @ [] = ?xs
```

Unlike `simp_trace`, it will not tell you what order the theorems were applied in. It is, however, capable of working with *every* method (`simp`, `clarsimp`, `fastforce`, `auto`, etc), while `simp_trace` only works with methods based on the simplifier.

To use it, you will need to grab both the files [`Apply_Trace_Cmd.thy`](https://github.com/seL4/l4v/blob/master/lib/Apply_Trace_Cmd.thy) and [`Apply_Trace.thy`](https://github.com/seL4/l4v/blob/master/lib/Apply_Trace.thy) and import `Apply_Trace_Cmd`.

Comment: Cool! I hope something like this finds its way into Isabelle proper.