# Find Lemmas used by simp/auto/clarify

Tags: isabelle

How can I find which lemmas are used by the simp, auto methods, etc?

In one concrete case, I have a goal like:

```
lemma "x ∉ dom S ⟹ Something"
apply auto
```

and after applying `auto` I get: `¬ Something ⟹ ∃y. S x = Some y`. I would like to find out why the whole goal is reversed like this, so that I can delete the respective rules from the rewriting.

I already tried `using [[simp_trace_new mode=full]] apply auto` and `using [[simp_trace]] apply auto`, but did not find information about what exactly caused `auto` to do this transformation.

Comment: `auto` and `clarify` do some classical reasoning on your lemma and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to trace that. Also `x ∉ dom S ⟹ Something` and `¬ Something ⟹ ∃y. S x = Some y` are logically equivalent. Why can't you work on the second form of the lemma?

Comment: I had some other simplification rules with `x ∉ dom S` as a premise, so when it got moved to the right these other simplification rules could no longer be used. I changed everything to `S x = None` now, but my question is more how to see the used lemmas in general. Thanks for the hint with the classical reasoning, I did not think of that.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an easy way. You could ask on the mailing list for a reason why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is necroposting. But for everyone stumbling over this question now, I want to point out that `apply_trace` is what OP was searching for. For more info see davidgs answer in this thread: [Printing out / showing detailed steps of proof methods (like simp) in a proof in isabelle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825747/printing-out-showing-detailed-steps-of-proof-methods-like-simp-in-a-proof-in).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is no "necroposting" on Stackoverflow (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125967/644502 ). Another option available since Isabelle 2020 is the `thm_deps` command, which prints the direct dependencies of a theorem.