# Tracing tactics in Isabelle

Tags: trace, isabelle

Section 9.4 The Classical Reasoner of the Isar Reference Manual writes:

> The tactics can be traced, and their components can be called
>   directly; in this manner, any proof can be viewed interactively.

I have found sections in this manual about tracing the simplifier and higher order unification.

How can I trace e.g. the classical reasoner?

Comment: Maybe unrelated. but there is the `apply_trace` method from the l4.verified project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26827242/2743088