# Can resolution proofs be traced in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

`using [[simp_trace]]` let's you see what simplification rules were used and `using [[unify_trace_failure]]` let's you see what unification issues were encountered. I wonder if resolution proofs can be equally traced. This would make Isabelle proofs effectively [surveyable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-surveyable_proof).

Comment: i found one can do this traces  [[simp_trace,linarith_trace,metis_trace,smt_trace]] , ML_exception_trace and more by scanning the isabelle/isar manual for _trace

Comment: https://lists.cam.ac.uk/mailman/htdig/cl-isabelle-users/2015-March/msg00065.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think one can trace auto, blast,... step by step or get proof scripts from them. ([this](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2020-August/msg00008.html) mailing list thread should be interesting for you). What you can do is get a list of the used facts, for more details see davidgs answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825747/printing-out-showing-detailed-steps-of-proof-methods-like-simp-in-a-proof-in) thread.

Comment: indeed, there does not seem to be support for this (according to the user mailing list of today)